# Regular expression for SQL query to extract date range which is in String format

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How can I extract a date range from a string format field by using sql query. Here is a sample data

```
TABLE
------
AUDIT+1+2019-08-24T04:28:34
AUDIT+1+2019-10-22T12:36:11
AUDIT+1+2020-02-16T13:08:08
AUDIT+1+2020-02-18T15:08:08
```

I need to extract all the records with date lesser than **2020-02-18T15:08:08**

Comment: How is the data entered into the column?  Since it's a string, it could contain anything, especially if it is user-entered, so you may not be able to assume the data will always be in the correct format.  I suspect it's logging from a program but then it should be into a proper date column.  Do some sanity checking on the data first and see if there is any data that does NOT match what you assume to be in there before you settle on a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions comparisons:

```
where substr(col, -19) < '2020-02-18T15:08:08'
```

You are lucky that the string representation works for ordering, so you don't need to convert this to a date or timestamp.